# How to add metadata to jsTree from server JSON and retrieve the metadata

Tags: javascript, json, jstree

Here's how I'm setting up my jstree div:

```
$("#jsTree").jstree({
  'core' : {
    'data' : {
        'url' : 'users/initialize-jstree',
        'data' : function (node) {
            return { 'id' : node.id };
        }
    }
  }
}).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    console.log( data );
    console.log( data.node.text );
    console.log( data.testTestOne);

});
```

In the JSON I return from my URL, I include a metadata object like so:

```
{
    "id":3,
    "text":"My Node Text",
    "children":[],
    "metadata": {
        "testTestOne":"Test metadata 1",
        "testTestTwo":"Test metadata 2"
    }
}
```

Yet I can't seem to retrieve that metadata in the `.bind()`.

More specifically, other SO Q&A's don't work as `data.rslt` is always `undefined` for some reason,

Is there something wrong with how I'm providing it in the JSON from server, or how I've setup jstree?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get the `metadata` key using:

```
console.log(data.node.original.metadata);
```

However I would recommend using `data` instead of `metadata` in your response:

```
{
    "id":3,
    "text":"My Node Text",
    "children":[],
    "data": {
        "testTestOne":"Test metadata 1",
        "testTestTwo":"Test metadata 2"
    }
}
```

Then you can get the custom data using:

```
console.log(data.node.data);
```

Notice there is no `original` key which is not documented and might be removed, but `data` is documented and here to stay - so it is the safer place to store your data.

Comment: Where would `console.log(data.node.original.metadata);` evaluate? Wherever I seem to put it I get `node` as `undefined`

Comment: I've also tried, after page load, accessing specific nodes in the jsTree hierarchy - using `$('#1_anchor')` for example - and looking for similar fields but cannot find them